# Get modification date that can be used with touch -m

Tags: files, osx, date, timestamps, touch

I need to get the modification date of a file so that I can set it on other files using `touch -m`.

`stat` or `perl -le 'print((stat shift)[9])'` Didn't return what I wanted. I think that you are supposed to use - and + but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

I though that using the `-t` I though it could set it another way, here I tried to set it to 2013 July the 3rd.

```
touch -t  20130703
```

But that didn't change it the way I want either. So back to the question, how do I copy another files attributes so that I can set them with `touch -m`?

Comment: Why?  If you want to "copy another files attributes," why not use `touch -r`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but thats not what I want to do. I want to keep the string and maybe edit a folder and then change back the modification date etc.

Answer (score 4):

You may convert the time returned by `stat` or `perl` to the format you want with the command **`date`** (assuming you have GNU coreutils installed):

```
# Convert UNIX time returned by perl to year+month+day
$ date -d @$(perl -le 'print((stat shift)[9])' FILENAME) +%Y%m%d
20130703

# Convert formatted time returned by GNU stat to year+month+day
$ date -d "$(stat -c %y FILENAME)" +%Y%m%d
20130703
```

`date` itself can give you the modification time for files directly too:

```
$ date -r FILENAME +%Y%m%d
20130703
```

For details, see the [man page for GNU date](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#date-invocation) (`man date`).

Comment: Note that `stat -c` is specific to GNU `stat`. Most other `stat` implementations (including OS/X which the OP mentions) can specify the date format. GNU `find`'s `-printf` can also specify the date format.

Answer (score 2):

```
stat -f %m -t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S myfile
```

This prints the timestamp in the format required for `touch -t`.

Beware that the timestamp is expressed in the local timezone, which could be awkward to port files between timezones or for timestamps during the repeated hour of the summer-to-winter switch in timezones with DST. To avoid timezone trouble, use the UTC timestamp:

```
timestamp=$(TZ=UTC stat -f %m -t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S myfile)
…
TZ=UTC touch -t "$timestamp" myotherfile
```

Note that this applied to the BSD `stat` utility such as shipped with OSX, not to the GNU or BusyBox `stat` utilities such as found on Linux.

Comment: Note that to avoid issues around daylight saving switches, it's better to fix TZ to `UTC0` for both `touch` and `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing "ls -otr --time-style=+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" will get the date in the proper format, though with a bunch of other info that's easily edited out.

This is handy when assigned to an alias, and the output redirected to a file.

Comment: The OP tagged this OSX. `--time-style` is a feature of GNU coreutil's `ls`.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu and this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with [osx](/questions/tagged/osx), I will be assuming that the user is on macOS.

The `touch` utility on macOS is able to set the modification timestamp on a file when using its `-m` option.  The issue now is to find a way to set the modification timestamp with `touch -m` on a number of files using some separate file as the "reference file".

The user suggests using `stat` to parse out the modification timestamp from the reference file, but the `touch` utility on macOS can do this by itself by using `-r file`:

```bsh
touch -m -r reference_file file1 file2 file3
```

The above command sets the modification timestamp of `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` to the same timestamp as the modification timestamp on the file called `reference_file`.

If the user wants to keep track of the original timestamp of a file or directory somewhere (as is alluded to [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180356/get-modification-date-that-can-be-used-with-touch-m/699387#comment300090_180356)), to be able to restore it later, they could simply create an empty file and set the timestamp on that with `touch -m` as mentioned above, with `-r`.  At no time is it necessary to parse out the timestamp from `stat`.

```bsh
# create an empty file to hold the original timestamp
touch -m -r original empty

# do stuff to the original

# restore timestamp on the original
touch -m -r empty original
rm empty
```